# Why HTML get a mysteriously "margin" at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/rtVPb/1/) is quite easy :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body style="padding:0; margin:0;">
        <form method="post" action="/default.aspx" id="form1" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
          <div id="container-main" style="background-color:Red; height:1825px; position:relative;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div id="fascia-chiusura" style="background-color:#5CAE22; height:11px; position:relative; width:100%;">&nbsp;</div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But on Firefox/Chrome it gets a strange "space" at the bottom, which is not in the HTML element. Why this behaviour? And how can I fix it?

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Screenshot? or jsfiddle?

Comment: @chovy - The very first word is a link to a fiddle.

Comment: The div fascia-chiusura is placed underneath the main container. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes the code is what I want! In fact, I don't understand that "space" in the bottom!

Comment: I have tested it with FF 15.01, Opera 11.02 and Chrome 22, the page looks exactly the same...the only difference is in IE9, the bottom green bar is bigger there.

Comment: Fiddle you fint it in the top of the question! Added also the screenshot...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rtVPb/4/

Remove the `&nbsp;` in your last div and it works fine. The space from the `&nbsp;` is larger than the 11px defined in the div so it creates an overflow and you get a white part.
You can check this behaviour [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rtVPb/6/) where I added some visible text..

Comment: I like solving problems by removing code instead of adding code ;-) +1

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rtVPb/2/

Remove this:

```
 <div id="fascia-chiusura" style="background-color:#5CAE22; height:11px; position:relative; width:100%;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `overflow:hidden` to `<div id="fascia-chiusura"/>`

http://jsfiddle.net/rtVPb/9/

Comment: me too. seems rather useless to me. it's just a blank space. Use clearfix if you need to clear floats.

Comment: Ah, I see @QQping already has explained that. The `&nbsp;` is larger than the defined `11px`.

Comment: @chovy There are no floats here

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with anything, just remove last div height or change it to auto

http://jsfiddle.net/rtVPb/8/

Comment: This will make the `div` larger than the `11px` it needs to be.